# What's the difference between declined and disputed flags?

Tags: discussion

What's the difference between **declined** and **disputed** flags?

[image]

Comment: This has been answered on [metase]: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/141292/205264

Comment: @Camil Thanks for the link. It settles my curiosity..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Diamond moderators decline flags.

Any user using the review queue can dispute your flag.

Comment: Sorry, all the details I have, thought you might want an explanation.

Comment: That's good enough. You practically said the same thing as the answer Camil linked to, just in fewer words. Thanks! BTW, I hope I'm not keeping you too busy with my flagging :-)

Comment: @m.Alin if we did not want the flags, we would decline them. We generally only decline to leave feedback, we have to decline to leave a message.